# Group By Month clause issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by

I have a SQL query to group a number of products added to the system by month. I ran this query last week, and ran it again today. Today the results seem to be in a different order. Is it possible to run this query and have a second column showing the month?

Here is my original query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Products p
WHERE YEAR(t.CreatedDate) = '2013' 
  AND t.Deleted = 0 
  AND t.RemovedFromSale = 0
GROUP BY MONTH(t.CreatedDate)
```

This returns the following:

```
 | (No Column Name)
1| 2009
2| 161
3| 98
```

Ideally, I would like something like this:

```
 | (No Column Name) | Month Name
1| 2009             |  
2| 161              |
3| 98               |
```

Is this possible by altering my query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to return the `MONTH(t.CreatedDate)`, then you would need to include the column in your `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Total,
  MONTH(t.CreatedDate) as Month
FROM dbo.Products p
WHERE YEAR(t.CreatedDate) = '2013' 
  AND t.Deleted = 0 
  AND t.RemovedFromSale = 0
GROUP BY MONTH(t.CreatedDate)
```

The `MONTH()` will return the month as an integer. If you want to return the Month as it's name, then you will want to use [`DATENAME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Total,
  DATENAME(month, t.CreatedDate) as Month
FROM dbo.Products p
WHERE YEAR(t.CreatedDate) = '2013' 
  AND t.Deleted = 0 
  AND t.RemovedFromSale = 0
GROUP BY DATENAME(month, t.CreatedDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your SQL to

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MONTH(t.CreatedDate)
  FROM dbo.Products p
  WHERE YEAR(t.CreatedDate) = '2013' AND t.Deleted = 0 AND t.RemovedFromSale = 0
  GROUP BY MONTH(t.CreatedDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*), DATENAME(m, CreatedDate) [MonthName]
FROM dbo.Products p
WHERE YEAR(t.CreatedDate) = '2013' AND t.Deleted = 0 AND t.RemovedFromSale = 0
GROUP BY DATENAME(m, CreatedDate)
```